# (C#, HttpWebRequest)Timeout property is not working

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Request is not stopped after a period of time is passed set in Timeout.

I'd like to add a function to stop request automatically when a period of time is passed since the server has no response time to time.

Please find below source.

=========================================================================

```
String urlSetting = "http://www.test.com";

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlSetting) as HttpWebRequest;

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1);

Accept-Language:en";

request.MediaType = "text/html";

request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";

request.Timeout = 3000;

request.Proxy = new WebProxy() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

=========================================================================
I am using GetResponse() to call server, but sometimes the server does not response.

I added "request.Timeout = 3000;" to stop requesting when three seconds passed.

But that part doesn't work.

Internet environment here is proxy as below.

[proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGKg.png)

I wonder if there is another way for Timeout for proxy environment.

Comment: Can you try setting Timeout to a low value, say only 5?

Comment: Try using an IP address rather than a host name, to rule out the DNS (see the part just above "Examples" on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)